# Rounding decimal number only last two digit PHP

Tags: php

I have to round of only last two digits near 10 in PHP.

For example 
0.27777777777778 ->0.30

0.47777777777778 ->0.50

0.57777777777778 ->0.60

Comment: You mean to 1dp, not 2 going by your examples. Look at [round](http://php.net/round).

Comment: Here. Happy lecture: http://php.net/manual/en/function.round.php

Comment: If i use round of $input='0.27777777777778';echo $number = round($input,2); Output is :0.28 but i need nearest 10 like 0.30

Comment: Did you bother checking any of the two links in the previous two comments? I guess not.

Comment: Yes round function only round the value 0.277777777 to 0.28 but i need to round of nearest 10 like 0.30.

Comment: So rounding to 1 decimal and adding a 0...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$input=0.27777777777778;
$number = number_format(round($input,1),2);
echo $number;
```

Round your number to 0.3, then use number format to show two decimal points.

From the PHP manual / docs:

- Rounding numbers - [Link](http://php.net/manual/en/function.round.php)
- Number format - [Link](http://php.net/manual/en/function.number-format.php)

Comment: Thanks for the explanation too.